# Custom 404 error page for wrong urls with wordpress installation in root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a domain http://example.com with a wordpress installation. I have some subdomains too, they're working fine.
Now I want to make a custom 404 page for any url that doesn't exist on my domain. for example: http://notexistingsubdomain.example.com.

If I try this, I get a 500 error instead of a 404 error.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^subdir-name/.*$ - [PT]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How can I make the 404.php my custom 404 for every faulty url on my domain and subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress allow you tu use a 404.php file in your theme.
This file is use for all "404 error" and display ur template page.

It's the better way to make the 404.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div>Some text here !</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Put this file in theme. Then customize it.

I hope that help you.

ps: don't forget to remove your custom code in .htacces file.

Comment: I ended up using the 404 from the wordpress installation, but Whenever I type in an unexisting subdomain, I still get an 500 server error. How to fix that?